# Equivalent to MemoryStream that's full duplex/overlapped?

Tags: c#, memorystream

I'm doing a testbed client/server system (dotnet 4.0) that will eventually have two components communicating via streams across some transport medium, but at the moment has the two communicating via a single MemoryStream. Never used them before, and I made the assumption I could be writing and reading at the same time. However, because there's only one 'cursor' I can't be reading from the stream until it's finished writing and I can seek() back to zero.

The named pipe stuff supports full duplex operation, but only if I set one object up as the server and have the other connect to it- not something I'm wanting to do at this point.

I can get the result I want by creating a byte buffer and having two MemoryStream instances pointing at that buffer, but that falls over when I reach the end of the buffer and get an exception because the memory stream can't be expanded.

I could probably do this by creating a file instead of the array and having two FileStream instances, but that seems a somewhat messy way of doing it. And if left running would result in a full disk since nothing would be pruning the data that's been read.

What I'm after is a stream that doesn't support seek() or position, maintains separate read and write pointers, buffers data that's written to it and discards it sometime after it's been read. Feels like reinventing the wheel to roll my own. Surely such a thing is already around somewhere?

Comment: I am not aware of something like that existing.

Comment: Sounds like you want a ring buffer.

Comment: Hmmm. It sounds more like a queue to me.

Comment: The worst thing you could do setting up a "testbed client/server system" is to not pick a client and a server.  It matters.  A pipe or a socket or WCF are obvious choices.

Comment: You might be interested in my [ProducerConsumerStream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852), which has the behavior you describe. Note that it's a fixed size circular buffer, so if your writer seriously outruns your reader, the writer will stall.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've done a quick and dirty implementation that wraps a queue in a stream wrapper. @JimMischel; thanks- that's something I'll use if my present implementation starts suffering performance problems, since I suspect using Enqueue() and Dequeue() per byte is quite inefficient. @HansPassant; Perhaps but this is a very early test of some new crypto stuff we're playing with- at this stage we just want to play with data and all I've really determined about node to node comms is it'll be stream, rather than message, based, and is likely to involve embedded stuff so WCF's out.

Comment: @CraigGraham Not that I think this will be what you're after but FYI the .Net Micro Framework (used for embedded devices) supports [DPWS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh423016.aspx) which you can think of as "WCF light". A quick intro is [available here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/netmfteam/2009/02/11/getting-started-with-dpws-in-the-net-micro-framework/)